# Use asterisk in variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh, variable, escape-characters

I want to cat all files to one new file in a bash script.

For example there are three files in my dir:
- file_a.txt
- file b.txt
- file(c).txt

When I write the following, it works without problems:

```
cat "file"*".txt" >> out_file.bak
```

No I want to make it more flexible/clean by using a variable:

```
input_files="file"*".txt"
cat $input_files >> out_file.bak
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The question is why? (When I echo input_files and run the command in terminal everything is fine. So why doesn't it work in the bash script?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends when you want to do the expansion:

When you define the variable:

```
$ files=$(echo a*)
$ echo $files
a1 a2 a3
$ echo "$files"
a1 a2 a3
```

When you access the variable:

```
$ files=a*
$ echo "$files"
a*
$ echo $files
a1 a2 a3
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a `$` in the `cat` command which uses `input_files`. Try

```
cat $input_files >> out_file.bak
```

Comment: That's right, but only part of the problem.

Comment: My testing did not reveal a problem with whitespace.

Comment: You are right, excuse me.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to take more care if you have filenames containing whitespace. In that case, use an array:

```
input_files=( "file with space."*.txt )
cat "${input_files[@]}" >> out_file.bak
```

Comment: +1 this is the better way to store a list of files.

Comment: But this would also output files named "file with space." (Which is missing the *.txt part). Or does cat know that each part of the array must match?

Comment: No. `cat` doesn't "know" anything: the shell expands the glob pattern into the array, so the array contains just a list of filenames. Then the array expansion syntax provides cat with all the filenames. The glob pattern `"file with space."*.txt` will only match files ending with `.txt` and beginning with `file with space.` That's because there are no unquoted spaces in the pattern. Create a few sample files and test it for yourself